# Retrieve values for multiple ids given in the order

Tags: sql-server, csv, stored-procedures

I am having a stored procedure which uses CSV to accept multiple IDs. I want to retrieve the values from the table in the order of the Ids given. The stored procedure I am currently using is

```
   CREATE procedure [dbo].[Proc1]
   @Userid VARCHAR(MAX)=NULL
   as
   begin
   set nocount on;
    DECLARE @Useridord TABLE (Userid VARCHAR(MAX),Position int identity(1,1));
   INSERT INTO @Useridord 
   SELECT item
   FROM [dbo].[Split] (@Userid, ',')
   select * from User where User.UserId IN (select TOP 100 Percent Userid  from @Useridord ORDER BY Position)  
   end
   GO
```

What I am trying to do is from csv I am inserting the values into temporary table adding the order value as position. As I use Orderby Position, it is only implemented in the inner select. But the Output is given as the order in the table. I know to use an orderby in the outer select statement but I don't know the correct syntax to execute it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: select * from User where User.UserId IN (select Userid  from @Useridord ) ,, hav u tried like this?

Comment: But how do I order based on the position?

Comment: Results which is retrieved from the table ordered by temp table Position only, (unless you have Primary Key in User table)

Comment: Yes the User table has Primary key. Anyway thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `INNER JOIN`?

```
SELECT 
    u.* 
FROM User u
INNER JOIN @Useridord uo
    ON uo.Userid = u.UserId
ORDER BY uo.Position
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should guaranty position inside function like:

```
create function fnSplit(@users varchar(100), @del char(10))
returns @t table(userid int, pos int) as
begin
    insert into @t values(3,1),(2,2),(1,3)
    return
end
```

Then you can join directly on function result like:

```
Select u.* from users u
join fnSplit('','') s on u.id = s.userid
order by s.pos
```

Here is fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a8acc/4